# Given $f(x_1,x_2) = \min \{x_1,x_2 \}^\alpha$ find the partial derivatives for $x_1, x_2$

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Given the function

$$f(x_1,x_2) = \min \{x_1,x_2 \}^\alpha$$

I have to find the partial derivatives for $x_1,x_2$ but I am just unsure whether it is as simple as I think it is or if it gets a bit tricky. I know that for 
$$
f(x_1,x_2) = \min \{x_1,x_2 \} = \begin{cases} x_1  \ & \text{if} \ x_1 \leq x_2 \\ x_2 & \text{if} \ x_1 > x_2 \end{cases}
$$
Does this mean that for the given function we have
$$
f(x_1,x_2) = \min \{x_1,x_2 \}^\alpha = \begin{cases} x_1^\alpha  \ & \text{if} \ x_1 \leq x_2 \\ x_2^\alpha & \text{if} \ x_1 > x_2 \end{cases}
$$
and thus the partial derivatives will be
$$
\frac{ \partial f(x_1,x_2) }{ \partial x_1 } = 
\begin{cases}
\alpha x_1^{\alpha-1} \ & \text{if} \  x_1 \leq x_2 \\
0 & \text{if} \ x_1 > x_2 
\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
\frac{ \partial f(x_1,x_2) }{ \partial x_2 } = 
\begin{cases}
0 \ & \text{if} \  x_1 \leq x_2 \\
\alpha x_2^{\alpha-1} & \text{if} \ x_1 > x_2 
\end{cases}
$$
Can you clarify? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's exactly right, you just partition the plane in two and voila.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :)

Comment: I'd say that the partial derivates do not exist when $x_1=x_2$. Choosing one side as the limit is no more valid than choosing the other.